# Eclipse java debug can't edit code while running

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ide

I'm not sure how it happened but a whole bunch of settings in my Eclipse java ide are messed up. I am assuming that this is also the reason why changing code while its running doesn't work anymore for me. When I run it in debug mode, change something and save it the changes are not happening in the program. I also dont get any warm messages if I do something that can't be changed while the code is running like adding a method or a field. Does anyone know what the problem is? I could probably reset all my settings but I also have some settings that I want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

1. Ensure that Build Automatically is selected under the Project menu; and
2. Make sure you're using Java version 1.4 or greater (Window menu > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs.

Eclipse requires both of these conditions in order to perform hotswap debugging.

Comment: Thanks, build automatically was disabled for some reason :/

Comment: @HendrikHübner If your question was answered, please click the checkmark to the left of the answer so that future visitors know what helped you.